# Configuring org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have added jars apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar and log4j-1.2.15.jar in classpath and no configuration in log4j.properties. 
Getting no error, but unable to print in log file.I also have refered questions stackoverflow but it is not working for me. any suggestion on it will be appreciated.

Is Configuration needed in log4j.properties if rolling.RollingFileAppender is used

Log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <param name="BufferSize" value="256"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DROLLFILE" />

    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c %x - %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="DROLLFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" >
     <param name="threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
     <rollingPolicy name="file"  
                      class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" 
               value="/media/mgs1032/57403571-7065-47b8-88cd-1b20a9229764/ezeClick/ezeClickSetUp/PaymentGateWorkSpace/libs/logger/logs/ezeClick.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz"/>
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="/media/mgs1032/57403571-7065-47b8-88cd-1b20a9229764/ezeClick/ezeClickSetUp/PaymentGateWorkSpace/libs/logger/logs/ezeClick.log"/>
     </rollingPolicy>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout" >
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
               value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>


    <logger name="amex.quickpay" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really whats wrong with your code, but this works for me (wihtout log4.properties)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" monitorInterval="30" strict="true">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:catalina.base}/logs/</Property>
        <Property name="filename">appName.log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/${filename}" filePattern="${log-path}/${filename}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

EDIT: 
Note: this is for log4j 2